# How to set the fileName in the openRawResource() to be variable

Tags: android

I got an editText which allow the user to type the file name, but since all the files are in the raw folder. I tried to get the file from the raw folder and here is the problem,

```
String fileName = editText.getText().toString;
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_db_file);
```

how can I replace "my_db_file" to fileName? it seems not allow me to code it like this
 `InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);`
any idea? thanks so much for the help

Comment: Are you able to access the resource id of the folder with something like `R.raw.textfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to convert a `String` representing a resource name into a resource ID. Note that this uses reflection under the covers, so please cache your result.

Comment: What would you recommend to use for caching? Is [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) suitable?

Comment: @JJD: "What would you recommend to use for caching?" -- an `int`. My point about caching the result is mostly for loops, where you should look up the value and hold onto it in a local variable outside of the loop, rather than looking it up every pass through the loop.

Comment: I look-up a series of resource ids for files from the `raw` folder which content ends up as items of a list view. I consider using an `LruCache` to reduce the number of look-ups. Though, I am unsure about the initial size of the cache. [Example](http://pastebin.com/mXDeTx4u)