# How to change (R.raw.fileName) as the fileName is changing

Tags: android, resources

I got a editText which allow the user the type the file name, but since all the files are in the raw folder. I try to get the file from the raw folder and here is the problem,

`String fileName = editText.getText().toString;
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_db_file);`

how can I replace "my_db_file" to fileName? it seems not allow me to code it like this

`InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);`

thanks so much for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the fileName in the openRawResource() to be variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554265/how-to-set-the-filename-in-the-openrawresource-to-be-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in the raw folder can't be changed in the runtime. I don't know why you need to ask the user to input the file name. As far as I know, it's impossible to do so, since all the files in teh raw folder should be defined already before compilation.

Comment: @AndroidKiller  What I mean is that if the developer put a file already, say a.txt in the raw folder, he can ask the user to input a.txt to get access to that file, as you do. But if the developer didn't do that, the code can't create a file named a.txt. So I don't understand why OP needs to achieve this function, since the user can't input arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I replace "my_db_file" to fileName? it seems not allow me to
>   code it like this

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fileName);
```

You've done a terrible job of explaining your question, but I think your problem is the fact that you cannot simply "capture" the string entered by the user and insert that into your call to `openRawResource(R.raw.whatever_the_user_typed)`. The reason is based on a simple thing you need to understand which is that R.raw.filename actually refers to a static int inside of an static inner class. What this means is that as you drop files into the raw resources, the Android Asset Packaging Tool creates, at compile time, unique "code representations" of those resources so that you can refer to them in your code. So, the point is, in order to do what you want to do, which is very strange btw, you would need to do something like:

pseudocode:

```
switch(the user's input) {
  case: "foo"
     openRawResource(R.raw.foo)
  case: "whatever"
     openRawResource(R.raw.whatever)

}
```